# How do i solve the Trigger and raise_error output

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

The following trigger is to stop double bookings of rooms and to offer alternative rooms for appointments. I'm having a problem trying to show the rooms. Can you tell me where I've gone wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_APPOINTMENT 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF APP_DATE,C_NO,
RM_NO,APP_TIME ON APPOINTMENT
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

  CURSOR C_APP                   
  IS
  SELECT APP_DATE,C_NO,APP_TIME,RM_NO    
    FROM APPOINTMENT;

  V_APP_DATE APPOINTMENT.APP_DATE%TYPE;  
  V_APP_TIME APPOINTMENT.APP_TIME%TYPE;
  V_C_NO APPOINTMENT.C_NO%TYPE;
  V_RM_NO APPOINTMENT.RM_NO%TYPE;
  I_RM_NO APPOINTMENT.RM_NO%TYPE;
  RM_BKED_ERROR EXCEPTION;           

BEGIN
  OPEN C_APP;                    
  FETCH C_APP INTO V_APP_DATE,V_C_NO,V_APP_TIME,V_RM_NO; 

  IF :NEW.C_NO=V_C_NO           
 AND:NEW.RM_NO=V_RM_NO          
 AND:NEW.APP_DATE=V_APP_DATE         
 AND:NEW.APP_TIME=V_APP_TIME         
 THEN 
   RAISE RM_BKED_ERROR;      
 END IF;    

 SELECT R.RM_NO 
   INTO I_RM_NO
   FROM ROOM R,BRANCH B 
  WHERE R.RM_NO <> :NEW.RM_NO 
   AND B.BRN_NO = :NEW.BRN_NO
   AND B.BRN_NO=R.BRN_NO
 GROUP BY R.RM_NO;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN RM_BKED_ERROR THEN            
    Raise_Application_error (-20000, 'ROOM ALREADY BOOKED FOR AN APPOINTMENT.THE FOLLOWING ROOMS ARE AVAILABLE '||I_RM_NO); 
    CLOSE C_APP;
END;
 /
```

Comment: shimmerstrike:You are not allowed to fetch the table appointment inside the trigger `CHECK_APPOINTMENT` ,which is on the same table .Which version of oracle you are using .

Comment: :Rather than writing a trigger ,use a pl/sql block to insert/update data into appointment table.Other than than you need to create a compound trigger

Comment: @GauravSoni i'm using oracle 9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't look like a correct approach, as triggers are *notoriously* poor for enforcing constraints.

I would adopt one of the following methods:

1. Encapsulate the appointment booking code in a procedure which first gets an exclusive lock on the room record in whatever table that is in. Then it can check for overlapping records in the appointment table, and insert-and-commit if the period required is free. Return a code to indicate that the booking was successful or unsuccessful, and if it is unsuccessful perhaps also a list of other rooms which are available (and commit or rollback to free the room table lock). As the room unavailability is not an unexpected condition I would not use exception handling for this.
2. Create a separate table that has one row per room-minimal_booking_period (eg. 15 minutes), with a unique key on the room and interval identifier. Use that key violation to notify that the booking was not successful, but similarly to the first method do not pass an exception back to the application.